# ld: duplicate symbol. g++

Tags: c++, g++

Ok I'm trying to get my head around g++ and librarys. I have a few files that I've compiled into a library

from the make file

```
$(CC) -fPIC -c -o $@ $< -O2 -D__PS2
```

then

```
$(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJ_FILES) -O2 -D__PS2
```

this compiles fine.

from the program that uses the lib

```
$(CC) -c -o $@ $< -I./
```

compiles fine

```
$(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ_FILES) I./ -Llib -mootPS2lib.so
```

Linking the obj's together and it goes **BOOM!**

ld: duplicate symbol Moot::loggerInstance() in object_files/foo.o and object_files/main.o

**foo.hpp**

```
//include guards
#include <Moot/Logger.hpp>
class Foo
{
public:
    void show();
}
```

**foo.cpp**

```
 #include "Foo.hpp"
 void Foo::show() { Moot::loggerInstance().turnLoggerOn(true); }
```

the main.cpp only includes foo and calls the show method.

Thanks for anyhelp.

**UPDATE**
I wasn't clean with the details of the question, sorry.

I've got this working on Windows by making it a static library.

Logger.hpp looks like this. * Its not quite finished so I know there are a few things missing. but it works.

```
#ifndef MOOT_LOGGER_HPP
#define MOOT_LOGGER_HPP

#include <Moot/Platform.hpp>
#include <Moot/Utilities.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

namespace Moot
{
    //! Outputs info to a text file. By default the logger is off.
    //! On the PS2 cout is used to output info onto the screen.
    class Logger
    {
        Logger()
        {
            std::ofstream logfile;
            logfile.open ("logfile.txt", std::ios::trunc);
            logfile << "LogFile - most recent at the bottom\n";
            logfile << "-----------------------------------\n \n";
            logfile.close();

            m_isLoggerOn = false;
        }


        Logger(const Logger&);
        Logger& operator=(const Logger&);

        ~Logger() {}

        bool m_isLoggerOn;

        template <typename T>
        void logMessage(T type)
        {
            # if (MOOT_ON_PS2)
                std::cout << type;
            # else
                std::ofstream logfile;
                logfile.open ("logfile.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::app);
                logfile << type;
                logfile.close();
            #endif
        }


        //! Overiden << to allow you string together types.
        template <typename T>
        Logger& operator<< (T type) 
        {
            if (m_isLoggerOn) logMessage(type);

            return *this;
        }


        //! Overiden << to allow you string together types.
        Logger& operator<< (std::wstring wideStr)
        {
            if (m_isLoggerOn) logMessage(Moot::Utilities::convertWstringToString(wideStr));

            return *this;
        }

    public:

        //! Instance of the logger.
        static Logger& getInstance()
        {
            static Logger log;
            return log;
        }

        //! Switch Logging off or on. It is set to off by default.
        void turnLoggerOn(bool setLogger)
        {
            m_isLoggerOn = setLogger;
        }

    }; // Logger


    Logger& loggerInstance()
    {
        return Logger::getInstance();
    }


    //! Convenience variables
    namespace {
        Logger& lStart    = loggerInstance();
        const char lEnd   = '\n';
    }
} // Moot


#endif
```

Comment: The problem appears to be located in `Logger.hpp`. Can you show the definition how `loggerIstance()`?

Comment: Sorry I should have included logger. Thanks

Comment: Make note that you have not guarded Foo.hpp against double inclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to declare `loggerInstance` inline.

This is the real use of the `inline` keyword. Your function will be inlined if the compiler wishes, but it won't be defined twice.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you have something like this in your logger.h file:

```
namespace Moot
   {
   LoggerInstance &loggerInstance()
      {
      static LoggerInstance myself:
      return myself;
      }
   }
```

This is a common approach for implementing a singleton (albeit not completely threadsafe).

The solution is to move the implementation of loggerInstance to a separate .CPP file.

Comment: Thats what I did, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your headers are only included once. i.e.

```
#ifndef M_H
#define M_H
//Your code
#endif
```

Seems to me that there is a double inclusion of a header.

Comment: I have link guards, was first thing I checked. Which left me abit puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you actually need to include `Logger.hpp` in your `Foo.hpp` . Try including it in `Foo.cpp` where the Logger object is actually used.

As a general rule, don't include things in headers unless you absolutely need to as doing so can create dependencies that don't need to be there. I.e.

**foo.hpp**

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

class Foo 
{ 
public: 
    void show(); 
}

#endif // FOO_HPP
```

**foo.cpp**

```
 #include "Foo.hpp" 
 #include <Moot/Logger.hpp>
 void Foo::show() { Moot::loggerInstance().turnLoggerOn(true); }
```

Comment: Ah, I see, I've been including everything in the headers :/

Comment: @PhilCK: The real problem was the (non-inline) definition of `Moot::loggerInstance` in the header file. For non-inline function, only a single definition can occur in a program, but including "Moot/Logger.hpp" in the "Foo.hpp" header caused the "Moot/Logger.hpp" file to be included in both .cpp files and as a consequence two definitions of the `Moot::loggerInstance` function.